# how to scrap phobos website using open url

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, tor

I'm trying to scrap phobos website using bs4 and getting 418 teapot error Here is my code ....I am getting error when i am using build_opener.open

```
    from urllib.request import urlopen, Request, build_opener
from sockshandler import SocksiPyHandler
import socks
import pandas as pd
import urllib

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
phobos = "http://phobosxilamwcg75xt22id7aywkzol6q6rfl2flipcqoc4e4ahima5id.onion/search?query=data"
def clear(toclear):
    str = toclear.replace("\n", " ")
    return (' '.join(str.split()))
#headers = {'User-Agent': 'M',}
req = build_opener(SocksiPyHandler(socks.SOCKS5, "127.0.0.1", 9050, True))
res = req.open(phobos).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(res, 'lxml')
print(soup)
        
        
        
        
#main
```

HTTPError: HTTP Error 418: I'm a teapot

Actually, it is an onion site which you can access only with TOR Browser and not with normal browsers like chrome.

I want to scrap its results but it is giving me 418 teapot error

If you want to know any other information just comment here, I will try to answer it

Comment: What is a *phobos website* and where did you get that URL from?

Answer (score 0):

As a tidbit / Internet curiosity, the error you got is

> The HTTP 418 I'm a teapot client error response code indicates that the server refuses to brew coffee because it is, permanently, a teapot. A combined coffee/tea pot that is temporarily out of coffee should instead return 503. This error is a reference to Hyper Text Coffee Pot Control Protocol defined in April Fools' jokes in 1998 and 2014.

**The bottom line is** *Some websites use this response for requests they do not wish to handle, such as automated queries.*

Comment: Hi @baduker, so basically you are saying that there is no way to scrap this website?